# How to solve this asymptotic complexity problem?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, asymptotics

The increasing order of following functions in terms of asymptotic complexity is:
[image: complexity problem]

(A) f1(n) < f4(n) < f2(n) < f3(n)

(B) f1(n) < f2(n) < f3(n) < f4(n)

(C) f2(n) < f1(n) < f4(n) < f3(n)

(D) f1(n) < f2(n) < f4(n) < f3(n)

I saw this question on GeeksQuiz but I am unable to understand its answer. The correct answer is D.

I think that f(2) will have the highest complexity among all because for a given number it will give the maximum output.

Please help and explain how is it solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting functions by asymptotic growth](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_3(n)$ has the highest asymptotic time since it is an [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function). Although it is $(1+\epsilon)^n$ and might seem very tiny in terms of growth, there exists a real number $m$ where it grows faster than the rest.

Then, we have $f_4(n)$ as [quadratic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function).

$f_2(n)$ is unfortunately linear. Which means, it does not grow as fast as $f_4(n)$ and $f_2(n)$. Actually, while considering asymptotic growing, you should ignore the constants in the function. Thus, we can say that $O(1000000n) = O(n)$.

The tricky part is $f_1(n)$. It would grow faster than $f_2(n)$ if it was $O(n \log n)$. However, it is $O(n^{1-\epsilon} \log n)$, which makes it grow slower than a linear function.

Comment: is it true that exponential function will always have the highest asymptotic time?

Comment: @DeepanshuGabba compared to linear, logarithmic, and polynomial, yes it will always have the highest growth rate.

Comment: Remember that this is about _asymptotic_ behaviour. You can ask yourself: For which n is f3 (n) > f1 (n), for example, and that will be a very, very large n. You can also ask yourself: How large is f4 (n) when f3 (n) > f4 (n). These are useful things to know in practice, but the question was for asymptotic behaviour.